# Why the GCC auto-vectorization is -also- dependent on the type of the loop iteration variable?

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I have a simple function with a loop. GCC is able to vectorize the loop in this function. My GCC version is 4.7.4.

```
void  __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo(int *__restrict__ ptr1,  int *__restrict__ ptr2, int *__restrict__ ptr3, unsigned int cnt)
{
unsigned int i;

ptr1 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr1, 32);
ptr2 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr2, 32);
ptr3 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr3, 32);

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
 {
    ptr3[i] = ptr1[i] * ptr2[i];
 }
}
```

However, when I change the type of the function parameter cnt from unsigned int to int, GCC is not able to optimize the loop.

```
void  __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo(int *__restrict__ ptr1,  int *__restrict__ ptr2, int *__restrict__ ptr3, int cnt)
{
unsigned int i;

ptr1 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr1, 32);
ptr2 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr2, 32);
ptr3 = __builtin_assume_aligned (ptr3, 32);

for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
 {
    ptr3[i] = ptr1[i] * ptr2[i];
 }
}
```

The loop is not vectorized in this new version of foo. And the GCC output for the loop is:

**142: not vectorized: data ref analysis failed D.62366_17 = *D.62365_16;**

It seems that GCC requires the parameter and the variable it uses in the loop iterarion with the same exact type. Why the vectorization is dependent on the loop iteration variable type in this case?

Comment: Does it vectorize if `i` is changed to `int` in the second example?

Comment: Yes it does vectorize when i is changed to int.